# XSL: Get data from referred element in XML (ref, id)

Tags: xml, xslt, reference

I would like to get the the name of an author-element which is referred by a book-element in a XML file but I haven't figured out yet how to access it.

Down below is my XSL code and a sample of how my XML looks like.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/library">
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="librarytable.css" type="text/css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Bibliothek</h2>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Titel</th>
          <th>Jahr</th>
          <th>Autor(en)</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <xsl:for-each select="book">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="year"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="author-ref"/></td>
        <!-- author-ref just to fill in the blank-->
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is how book and author are connected in my XML:

```
<book>
    <author-ref>T.Pratchett</author-ref>
    <title>The Colour of Magic</title>
    <year>1983</year>
</book>

<author id="T.Pratchett">
    <last-name>Pratchett</last-name>
    <first-name>Terry</first-name>
</author>
```

Here is how it looks like but instead of T.Pratchett I would like to have Terry Pratchett in the table cell for example.

[image: Book Table]

I would be very grateful if anybody knows how to solve this problem.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a key to look up the `author` elements by their `id` attribute.

```
<xsl:key name="authors" match="author" use="@id" />
```

So, to look up the author for a current book you would do this...

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('authors', author-ref)"/>
```

Try this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:key name="authors" match="author" use="@id" />

<xsl:template match="/library">
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="librarytable.css" type="text/css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Bibliothek</h2>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Titel</th>
          <th>Jahr</th>
          <th>Autor(en)</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <xsl:for-each select="book">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="year"/></td>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="key('authors', author-ref)/first-name"/>
          <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="key('authors', author-ref)/last-name"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is what I was looking for!